# Apple Music checkbox is disabled and greyed out in Music

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, music, apple-music

In the restrictions for Music, the Apple Music checkbox is disabled, and greyed out.

[image: image of greyed out apple music box]

Things I tried/checked:

- I am the administrator on this mac.
- I'm signed in to iCloud on this computer.
- I can sync my library to my Apple ID.
- Restarting the computer
- Restarting music

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called Apple and they helped me in about 10 minutes, all you need to do is enable iTunes. For some reason, you need iTunes enabled to have Apple Music enabled.